# Make mouth/mandible for the face of the alien species

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to make a mouth for an alien species, and I don't know how to make the mouth look mandible-like, nor how to carve it out. I have tried sculpting it and booleans, but they didn't seem to work. The method shown in the picture is by using a boolean.
[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cq1SVJ363t8Dlck8OrcXL0aBeQrAF-uh/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Comment: I can't open your file, but generally speaking try to avoid boolean when you can, maybe follow some tutorials about animal modeling

Comment: Why can't you open my file?